# I'm having a problems with white part in .html or .css I don't know I'm new to coding

Tags: html, css

The problems that I have is that
1st. the image will change when I resize the window but the text won't
2nd. when I put the browser window to the side there is a white box
Please help me with this 2. I'm getting annoyed
I was going as the "Free HTML and CSS3 Course" to make you own website by Bring Your Own Laptop.

Comment: Pleasse upload some code and also some snapshots of the result

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We couldn't got any image or code. So it's hard to tell but for 1st problem I think you are setting font-size in px(pixel). Means it will take a fixed amount of screen size. You could try with something else as abir sikder said em or vw or %.

Also I think
`box-sizing: border-box;` will help

Answer (score 0):

you did not share your source code. Regarding your problem what you can do:

1. set padding and margin 0 to the body of your HTML.
2. set font size in em, or vw of your text.
3. write your own css media queries to make a responsive website.